# Batch script. How to arrange data according to a specific line

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I wanted  to arrange port unto their specific ip address

Text:

```
IP Address:, 10.0.0.2
5900/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.1 
139/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.13
445/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.2
139/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.2 
445/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.2
443/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.1
1311/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.13
1443/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.1
443/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.13
1311/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.2
1443/tcp 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.13 
IP Address:, 10.0.0.2
IP Address:, 10.0.0.1
```

The output should be
Output:

```
10.0.0.1
139/tcp
443/tcp
1311/tcp

10.0.0.2
5900/tcp
139/tcp
445/tcp
443/tcp
1443/tcp

10.0.0.13
445/tcp
1443/tcp
1311/tcp
```

Code i have done so far.
Code:

```
SET "ip= "

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%h IN (nx.txt) DO (
IF "%ip%"=="%%h" GOTO processq
SET "ip=%h"
ECHO %%h >> ReportNex.txt
ECHO %%i >> ReportNex.txt
)

GOTO :eof

:processq
ECHO %%i >> ReportNex.txt

GOTO :eof
```

Any ideas on how am i going to achieve that output?
I am thinking of either creating a new file to contain each ips port or using GOTO function

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to make your own attempts, share your efforts and describe precisely where you are stuck. Please learn [ask] here! Could there be more than one `*/tcp` line after an `IP Address:` line, or is there always only one at most?

Comment: @aschipfl Yeap i actually did it. But i just wasnt working well so i did not post it.

Comment: If it would work perfectly you wouldn't ask a question here, would you?

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I provide a script here, because I like the challenge. Anyway, please share your attempt and describe the trouble you are facing next time! Here it is:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (path to input file; use first command line argument)
set "_HEAD=IP Address:" & rem // (prefix of header used to build a new block)

rem // Deplete buffers:
for /F "delims==" %%V in ('2^> nul ^(set "$" ^& set "#"^)') do set "%%V="

rem // Phase I: read input file into memory:
set "NAME=" & set /A "COUNT=-1"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%I in ("%%L") do (
        if "%%I"=="%_HEAD%" (
            set "NAME="
            for /F %%S in ("%%J") do (
                set /A "COUNT+=1, INDEX=-1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                set "COUNT=00000000!COUNT!"
                for /F %%C in ("!COUNT:~-8!") do (
                    endlocal
                    if not defined #%%S set "#%%S=%%C"
                )
                set "NAME=%%S"
                for /F "tokens=2 delims=[=]" %%V in ('2^> nul set "$%%S["') do (
                    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%%V") do (
                        if "%%Z"=="" (set /A "INDEX=0") else set /A "INDEX=%%Z"
                    )
                )
            )
        ) else (
            if defined NAME (
                set /A "INDEX+=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                set "INDEX=00000000!INDEX!"
                if "!LINE:~-1!"==" " set "LINE=!LINE:~,-1!"
                for /F "delims=" %%E in ("$!NAME![!INDEX:~-8!]=!LINE!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "%%E"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

rem // Phase II: writing output data to console:
for /F "tokens=1* delims=#=" %%I in ('2^> nul set "#"') do (
    set "#%%I=" & set "#_%%J=%%I"
)
set "FLAG="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=#=" %%I in ('2^> nul set "#"') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-2* delims=$[=]" %%A in ('2^> nul set "$%%J["') do (
        for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%%B") do (
            if "%%Z"=="" (
                if defined FLAG echo/
                set "FLAG=#"
                echo(%%A
            )
            echo(%%C
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Supposing the script is saved as `assemble-data-blocks.bat`, call it with the input file ( `input.txt`, for instance) as a command line argument:

```cmd
assemble-data-blocks.bat "input.txt"
```

To write the output data to a file (`output.txt`, for example) rather than to the console, use this (the input and output files must not be equal!):

```cmd
assemble-data-blocks.bat "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't normally bother providing a script when no effort has beem mabe by the OP, however after seeing aschipfl's attempt, I figured there must be a simpler way:

```bat
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,3 Delims=:, " %%A In ("input.txt") Do (
    If Not "%%B"=="" (Set "_=%Temp%\_$%%B.tmp"
        If Not Exist "!_!" (>"!_!" (Echo=&Echo=%%B))) Else (>>"!_!" Echo=%%A))
2>Nul Type "%Temp%\_$*.tmp">"output.txt" && Del/Q "%Temp%\_$*.tmp"
```

The input file is named `input.txt` and output file `output.txt`; change as necessary.

*It's not an exact match for the layout in the question but I suppose that's a small price for its simplicity.*